# Objects type casting in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, casting

Type casting with `enum` works really well in TypeScript until you want to do it via util function. Here is an example:

```js
enum MyTypes {
    FIRST = "FIRST",
    SECOND = "SECOND",
    THIRD = "THIRD"
}

type TFirst = {
    type: MyTypes.FIRST
    foo: string
}

type TSecond = {
    type: MyTypes.SECOND
    foo: string
}

type TThird = {
    type: MyTypes.THIRD
    bar: string
}

type TMyObject = TFirst | TSecond | TThird

const someFunction = (myObject: TMyObject) => {
    if (myObject.type === MyTypes.FIRST || myObject.type === MyTypes.SECOND) {
        // here typescript knows exactly that myObject is TFirst or TSecond
        console.log(myObject.foo)
    }
}

const isFirstOrSecondUtil = (myObject: TMyObject): boolean => {
    return myObject.type === MyTypes.FIRST || myObject.type === MyTypes.SECOND
}

const otherFunction = (myObject: TMyObject) => {
    if (isFirstOrSecondUtil(myObject)) {
        // typescript is aware that myObject is TMyObject, but does not know which type exactly
        console.log(myObject.foo)
    }
}
```

You can test it in [TypeScript Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngFTgB2AZygbwFBT1AMQEkAlAZQSgF4oAiY8hWgGl3zIFEBhAeQDkAItTqdeglmzwIAEqSE1aMubWwBfbNgAuKYFAQEAlgCc0m4TnxRtqAFyxEOtADoGFSVABmAey93TRgxAAczUNa10EMmAAYy8QABNzd3C7eCRUZ1F+AXdvXyh-QJD1LR09BAALY0SaC3wU+3T0JyUSHMsAIwBDIz9NAODQ0tQ9eB4OgCsYsxp9Y1MoAB89KNiEpfKqo3iNNYW0LwhgAjAQaM0DOOEACgg4canzuwQxyemASmoAPix3Aw8oLd7m9zk5wtQqDQ0o4XKQKEtlncHtMwWVIVCHBknFlBJ86pY8AB6QlQCrAIy6cJoaIBZBmADWIC8AHcMMAAB5dc4AGzgVgqXTMSJBZgMGDmJjMXiMKxicR2BPwey83OATm5XiCQORoLy73c6hKe1FaEMkp4RlW8oAqhduTdhY9NM9Xk73nYOj5VV0QN9fpYKZowEZfY6UeD0Y0Ya5KItEcCnaiRpHoVicTkjXEFl5NGSjCczhcrjRtSKXQmPn78VB-oCxWbTBarQlbQZuaW3Xj3JZiVZHDSDHSaxgusyepSBUKK+dh6Np5pmFAOmAzPEvOgoEyGUzmVBmVVohU+yMOVzNLzu0qsyq1RqtWHdT59ZZDdggA).

As you can see on line 27 inside `someFunction` TypeScript is fully aware that `myObject` is of type `TFirst` or `TSecond` even though that function receives `TMyObject`. I am able to use `myObject.foo` without any problems since this property both of types have.

On the other hand I am using util function `isFirstOrSecondUtil` (which does the same checking as it is done in `someFunction`) inside `otherFunction` and apparently type checking fails in this case. On line 38 TypeScript does not know which type exactly is `myObject`. I would expect to be able to console `myObject.foo`, but TypeScript fails with `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'TThird'.`

Any suggestion how to do proper type casting via util function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Typescript that the boolean returned indicates the type:

```
 const isFirstOrSecondUtil = (myObject: TMyObject): myObject is TFirst | TSecond => 
   myObject.type === MyTypes.FIRST || myObject.type === MyTypes.SECOND;
```

[docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: Wow! That's amazing. Thanks for quick answer.